# Error text is hard to read on team page

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, old-teams, error-message

> [image: screenshot of white-on-white error message]

*Uh… how many seconds is that?*

The background should be red, not light grey.

Comment: There's a substantial difference between 'hard to read' and 'impossible to read' :-)

Comment: The answer: 3 seconds :P

Comment: @rene smells like a dupe.

Comment: Actually, the foreground text, rather than the background, should probably be red, yes?

Comment: @paxdiablo The background is red everywhere else on the site (for example if you push the flag button on this post twice within 3 seconds).